# python generate json output from input file

Tags: python, json

I have file with similar input :

```
lin1,line2,line3
lin1,line2,line3
lin1,line2,line4
```

and need convert it to JSON with Python. For example, output should be like this:

```
{
    "localport_starts_from": 1080,
    "config": [
        {
            "1": "lin1",
            "2": "line2",
            "3": "line3"
        },
        {
            "1": "lin1",
            "2": "line2",
            "3": "line3"
        },
        {
            "1": "lin1",
            "2": "line2",
            "3": "line3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have never worked with the `json` library, so can you show me an example of how to make this?

Comment: You are not showing us your whole input. Where does `"localport_starts_from": 1080,` come from? How are we to know that your input belongs in an array called `"config"`? Should the last line of the  3rd dict in `"config"` actually be `"3": "line4"` according to your example input? Why are the dict keys `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"` in quotes - shouldn't they be ints? Please [edit] your question and add as many details as possible. Finally, please look over the documentation for [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to familiarize yourself with the module.

Comment: this not change ""localport_starts_from": 1080"

Comment: We'll need code to go much further, but don't sweat the json part. Construct a python dict with the content you wnat then use `json.dumps` to jsonize the whole thing wit ha single call.

Answer (score 1):

Use the csv module to parse the input and the json to dump the parsing.

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    rows = list(csv.reader(f))

# rows will be a list of lists, where each inner list contains the values formerly separated by commas
# e.g. [["lin1", "line2", "line3"], ...]

# enumerate(row, 1) returns a generator of [(1, "lin1"), (2, "line2")...]
row_dicts = [{str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(row, 1)} for row in rows]

# now gather the rest of your stuff into a dict
# ....

result_dict["config"] = row_dicts

with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
     json.dump(result_dict, f)
```